# Add prefix to routes in React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-router-v4

I want to create a prefix for some paths in React Router v4, such as `v1` in front of all my routes for version 1 of my app. Here's what I've tried:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <App path="v1" >
      <Switch>
        <Route path="login" component={Login} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </App>
    <Route component={NotFound}/>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Here's `App`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../Assets/logo.svg';
import '../Assets/css/App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
     return (
       <div>
         {this.props.children}
       </div>
     );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Currently I am using this approach but it doesn't seem to working.
When I go to `http:\\localhost:3000\v1\login` it shows the `NotFound` component.
Any help here?

Comment: Can we see `App`?

Comment: Ok check again:)

Comment: Try to remove second `<Route component={NotFound}/>` and see what hapeens. Most likely it is being matched there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `App` as a container, restructure your routes like so:

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
      <Route path="/v1" component={App} />
      <Route component={NotFound}/>
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This will make `App` render whenever you navigate to `/v1` or `/v1/whatever`. Then, in `App`, instead of rendering children, render your other routes:

```
render() {
  const { match } = this.props;

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${match.url}/login`} component={Login} />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>      
  );
}
```

Thus, `App` will render a `Switch` with two possible routes. `match.url` here is `v1` because it matched the URL part `v1`. Then, it creates a route with `${match.url}/login` which results in `v1/login`. Now, when you navigate to `v1/login` you'll get the `Login` component.

Comment: ok , but is there any way where we can do it with in routing files instead of component files so my routing logic is more organized in routing folders?

Comment: @LakshayJain I don't think so, unless you explicitly lay out each and every single possible route. In previous React Router versions, you could have nested routes to accomplish exactly what you want, but in v4, it's not possible unless you do it this way.

Comment: So should i create layouts file for each prefix and use it as routing file like your answer?

Comment: @LakshayJain It all depends. I would personally organize each versions into folders (such as v1, v2, etc). Then in `App`, use `require` to import dynamically such as `const Login = require(\`${match.url}/Login.js\`)`.

Comment: Ok thanks for helping me i also figure out how to do the same with my approach with the help of your example.. I posted it in answer

Comment: In the more general case, where the parent match may contain path params, it's better to use `path={\`${match.path}/login\`}` instead of `path={\`${match.url}/login\`}` to match subroutes. `match.url` might have a value like `/users/12345` whereas `match.path` will have a value like `/users/:userId`. If you want the inner match to provide the `userId` param, using `match.path` allows that inner router to pick up the params defined for the outer router. Pardon that terrible rhyme.

Answer (score 38):

Came across a similar problem. Ended up using `<BrowserRouter basename='/v2'>`
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

Comment: Works with v5 too.

Answer (score 4):

If some one want to still use prefix in router file

```
import {BrowserRouter , Route , Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../Components/v1/App';
import React from 'react';
import NotFound from '../Components/404';
import Login from '../Components/v1/Login'

var v1="/v1";

const IndexRoute = (
    <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
              <App path={v1}>
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path={`${v1}/login`} component={Login} />
                    <Route component={NotFound} />
                  </Switch>
              </App>
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
export default IndexRoute;
```